# Internet Explorer throws error on printing

Tags: printing, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

When I try to print a page through the IE11 browser, I am getting an error that reads:

```
Cannot find
'file:///C:/Users/DANEMM~1/AppData/Local...:blank'.
Make sure the path or Internet address is correct.
```

[image: IE Error message]
Then I can click okay and proceed, but the page does not print.

The page will print fine from Firefox or Chrome so the problem seems to be with IE rather than the print driver. I have found some suggestions online to disable UAC and turn of IE protected mode. I tried both suggestions and they had no effect. What might be causing this problem?

Answer (score -1):

remove windows update KB4022719

Comment: While this might be an answer it would be good to state why this would fix the problem  how to go about doing it.

Comment: I know its not really an answer but it pointed me in the write direction to fix the problem.